# What do the numbers mean in Kmodes (python) result array?

Tags: python

I'm currently using Kmodes library acquired from https://github.com/nicodv/kmodes. 
My input dataframe has categorical attributes, but they are in string format... like below

[input data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eHmbf.png)

But when I run kmodes and print cluster centriods, it returns an array like below.

```
[[4 1 0 0]
 [4 0 2 0]
 [0 3 0 0]
 [0 2 0 0]
 [4 0 0 0]]
```

And I have no idea what these numbers represent. I just assume four elements in the list mean four attributes, but then what is '4' as 'location'? I tried to match the numbers with the result of unique(), but it doesn't seem right..

Answer (score 0):

The nunber in these arrays represent the modes of the four parameters: Location, Season, Time, and Weather. I am assuming that you set 5 clusters. I suggest that you transform your dataset into numerical representations of the categories, not strings. If you have a mixture of numeric data and categorical data I suggest you use the k-prototype.